# SAS Reading data through infile statement

Tags: sas

I want to read a tab delimited data using the infile statement in SAS. my text input has the following column format
x y z x y z

I tried the following command but it just outputs only the left half of the text file. How can i fix my code inorder to generate also the right half of my input data?

```
data newFile;
infile 'C:\filedirectory\file.txt' firstobs=5 dlm='09'x;
input x y z;
run;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the double @@ to hold the line pointer on the same line. 
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002645786.htm

```
Input x y z @@;
```

Comment: Thanks and it did work through that way. I really appreciate the help.